# iPhone app doesn't stay installed (icon disappears)

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I'm trying to install Zxing on my iphone from source (I know I can get it at the app store, but I want to modify some things in it).

The problem I'm having is that the app won't stay installed on the phone. It will run without a problem, but no icon will appear after I quit the app. I thought it had to do with my manually editing the codesign information in the project.pbxproj but after the developers changed the codesign identity they had left in the checked in version, the problem still persists.

I tried deploying an app I had developed from scratch and that worked fine.

I'm new to this, so any help would be much appreciated. You can download the zxing code from here:

svn checkout http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ zxing-read-only

Comment: Hmm, I removed this info the day you contacted me (developer). Not sure that qualifies as 'not providing any answers'.

Comment: I must have checked out a version between when we got in touch and when you checked it in. Wasn't aware you had changed it. My bad.
The problem still persists, even with a clean checkout, so it might not be zxing's fault. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded a copy from the App Store? I had one app (built from Xcode) that wasn't staying around after a sync and I found it was because iTunes was looking at my application syncing preferences and it wasn't selected to sync (as I had the Xcode build version on there, I didn't want to sync that version). However, it presumably removes the built app because I said I didn't want to sync *any* version of it.

Checking the checkbox to sync the app in iTunes kept the Xcode built version on there without installing the App Store version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem had to do with my iPhone firmware. It might be a bug from Apple as I got an email from truphone saying that users were experiencing similar problems. I re-installed firmware, and could install it fine, and sync other apps. As soon as I did a restore from a previous backup, it broke again... what a pain. Case closed.